# Error on Package Installation - In field: object - no CustomObject named WorkFeedbackRequest > found

Tags: error, package, permission-sets, servicecloud, unmanaged-package

I have built an unmanaged package and was able to deploy it to several orgs.

Unfortunately at the current Service Cloud org I get the following error:

> In field: object - no CustomObject named WorkFeedbackRequest
>   found XX_Admin: In field: object - no CustomObject named
>   WorkFeedbackRequest found

XX_Admin is a permission set.
The object WorkFeedbackRequest is neither in the source org nor the destination org available and is not needed and used by my package. I have found out, that this object may have something to do with work.com settings, why I already tried to switch work.com off and on. I also tried to create the object, but nothing helped.

Do you have any advice on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had intensive contact with Salesforce Support the last days. The solution or workaround which might also help others, which was provided is the following:

> ROOT CAUSE OF THE ERROR even if Work.com components were not used
>   during the package development, the package installation was failing
>   later on missing Work.com features.
>
> Your developer org has active Work.com licenses, which is rare with
>   dev orgs and the target org doesn't have them.
>
> BELOW ARE THE 2 WORKAROUNDS.
>
> 1. To recreate the package in an org without Work.com licenses. To move the package metadata, you can use Force.com IDE. This workaround
>      can fix the issue if the package is not installed in any customer orgs
>      yet. Since the package is installed in subscriber orgs, we would not
>      suggest this workaround: Due to the namespacing, any schema within a
>      package that has to be moved over to a new package will require their
>      subscribers to uninstall and re-install the new package, losing all
>      their data.
> 2. You can contact your ISV partner manager to clarify and remove the Work.com licenses.